# Is there any difference between these two TypeScript type declarations?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there any difference between these two declarations?

```js
// Use the <> notation
export type InvoiceEntity1<T extends InvoiceModel> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
// Do not use the <> notation
export type InvoiceEntity2 = new(...args: any[]) => InvoiceModel;
```

I'm just learing typescript and I'm trying to figure out how to work with generics.

Here, what I'm trying to do is to create a custom type where argument a type (a class) subclassing the `InvoiceModel`, for example:

```js
public foo({ entity: InvoiceEntity2 }): void {}
```

(Bonus question: I can't figure out how to make `foo` work with `InvoiceEntity1`).

Comment: The first is generic and the second is concrete.  `InvoiceEntity1<T>` refers to a *family* of constructor types, of which `InvoiceEntity2` is just one member (it is equivalent to `InvoiceEntity1<InvoiceModel>`).  An `InvoiceEntity1<InvoiceModel & {foo: string}>` is a constructor that produces `InvoiceModel` objects with an additional `string`-valued `foo` property.  If you have a use case or an [mcve] of what you're trying to do, someone can explain more clearly.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the explanation. What do you mean with "InvoiceEntity2 is concreter"? Im'm working on a simple example.

Comment: A concrete type is one which is not generic (or maybe one in which any generic type parameters have been resolved with other concrete types).  So `Array<T>` is generic if `T` is a generic type parameter, but `Array<string>` is a concrete type.